# How to load multiple markers in Google Map inside the Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, google-apps, map

Can anybody please advice

IF given with Address coordinates (X,Y) of each customer address in Salesforce, how can i put multiple marker for all the client in Salesforce that a company owns on top of google map inside a visualforce map.

Reading the google map api, i learned that GMAP api uses a delimeter (|) pipe to separate each
address, can anybody advice or propose a sample code

Answer (score 2):

Here is some advice (sorry no code).

1. See if you can get it to work with plain old HTML/JavaScript first on harcoded addresses
2. Then build the Apex code to retrieve the values you need to substitute in.

If you get those to both work independently then you should be able to "hook" their logic together.